# SSIS convert date in mmddyyyy format to date format using SSIS expression

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl, data-conversion

I'm receiving dates in a `MMddyyyy` format but want to convert it to the date format in SQL/SSIS `yyyy-MM-dd`, how can I do so using an SSIS expression.

An example of dates I'm receiving is `03051978` but want it to appear in `1978-03-05`.

Thank you

Comment: https://zappysys.com/blog/ssis-yyyymmdd-date-format-using-ssis-expression/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
(DT_DATE)(RIGHT("0000" + RIGHT("03051978",4),4) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + LEFT("03051978",2),2) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + SUBSTRING("03051978",3,2),2))
```

Just replace `"03051978"` with the column name, as an example:

```
(DT_DATE)(RIGHT("0000" + RIGHT([DateColumn],4),4) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + LEFT([DateColumn],2),2) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + SUBSTRING([DateColumn],3,2),2))
```

*Screenshot from SSIS expression tester tool*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your SSIS expression. Obviously, the assumption here is that day and month parts are always 2 digits:

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(col,5,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(col,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(col,3,2))
```

Comment: thank you! In the instance that there are only 1 digit for the month and date, how would the expression differ?

Comment: @HappyCoder123, it would make itself unusable. It will brake the entire parsing logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a script component.

```
DateTime.ParseExact([datecol],"MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```